# After clicking on a <a> tag - the new page is not at the top

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am using angular js - and when I click on a link the page that come is at the same level as the precedent and not at the top.

(I am not sure if my explanation is good, let me know)

Comment: Show us the code you've done so far.

Comment: On top of what exactly ?

Comment: It depends on what the link does, what kind of routing you're using, etc etc

Comment: sorry you question is so vague...

Comment: Do you mean the scrollbar ?

Comment: (I'm assuming the question means that the page doesn't scroll to the top when moving to another page.)

Comment: Yes normal Angular behaviour! It does not reload the page it GET the data from server and updates the view. Magic of AngularJs!

Comment: `$(window).scrollTop(0)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One thing i've done before is :

```
angular.module('myApp',['ui.router'])

.run(function($rootScope, $window){
    $rootScope.$on("$stateChangeStart", function () {
        $window.scrollTo(0, 0);
    });
});
```

Assumes you want to reset top on every route change

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague, but here are some things to consider:

-Use `$window.onfocus()` and you can call any functions then.

-There is also an attribute called `ngFocus` which may help you when you create the window. [This](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngFocus) could be a good reference.